# Clarification needed in Interface

Tags: java, interface

I know that interface can have only static and final values implemented inside it.. But is there any loophole by which I can change the value of 
a variable using interface?? The question may be absurd, but I m helpless since its my requirement. Here is the example piece of code..

```
public interface I {
    int val = 1;  
    int changeValue();

}
```

---

```
Class A implements I{
    int changeValue(){
        val = 2 ; 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How to change the value of 'val' using interface? 
Can I do something similar to:

```
val = changeValue();
```

Is there anything equivalent to do this functionality in an interface?

Comment: Interface variables are by default `public static final` and methods are by default `abstract public`. You can't use the `private` or `protected`modifier within an interface anyway. The sole purpose of an interface is to achieve publicly defined protocol behaviour.

Comment: Thank You @Lion .. please see my comments below, in answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot**. Interface variables are `static` and `final` by default.

A `final` variable is a variable that cannot be changed during the life of the object.

A `static` vairable is a *class variable* - it means there is only one value of it for all instances of the class (or interface in this case).

Thus - you only have one value for `I.x` - and this value cannot be changed.

---

What you might want to do, is define methods in your interface:

```
int getVal();
void setVal(int val);
```

And make the implementing classes implement the methods - so you will be able to use the variable with the `getVal()` and `setVal()` methods.

Comment: Variables in interfaces also are public by default.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: To be even more exact, everything in an `interface` is `public`

Comment: Thank You.. My actual requirement is such that I want to reuse, "Future<?>" in two methods of one class.. In 1st method, the value of "Future<?> changes and its being used back again in 2nd method.. I must not pass the values as parameter too. That is the reason why I selected Interface.. Now that knowing, its not feasible I have to think of some other option

Comment: @amit , can you kindly brief a little bit about your getVal() and setVal() way of changing the value of 'val' ??

Comment: @asvikki: It is not changing the value of `val` - it will let you define a new variable in each implementing class - but not change an interface variable - that cannot be done.

Comment: Clarification: "let you define..." really means - will let you a single API for changing/reading a newly added variable in each implementing class - but never the field that was declared in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this for an interface. However, it is possible to modify a `static final` variable in a class:

```
public abstract class I {
    static final int val; 
    static
    {
        val = 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class NotFinal
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(I.val); // Before: 1     

        Field field = I.class.getDeclaredField("val");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, 2);

        System.out.println(I.val); // After: 2
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Note that this does not work if you assign the value in the declaration, i.e.

```
static final int val = 1;
```

because the compiler treats this differently (as a constant) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301818/699224).

Comment: Looks interesting .. Thanks. I ll give a try with this

Comment: I don't actually recommend this approach - I merely point it out for academic purposes ;-)  There is almost certainly a better way, but you'd need to explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve, perhaps in a new question.

Comment: Ok, got it :) can you recommend something for my query, U can see that  in the first answer comments..